# Keras - using predefined training / validation split

Tags: image, tensorflow, split, keras, preprocessor

I'm working with Tensorflow/Keras. I have two text files (`train_{modality_name}.txt` and `val_{modality_name}.txt`). They contain the split I want to use for the images I'm processing.

The format of these files is the following:

```
example_0_path category_id
example_1_path category_id
...
example_N_path category_id
```

and my folder structure is like this:

```
/labels
    train_X.txt
    val_X.txt
/data
    /modality_1
    ...
    /modality_M
 (e.g. data/sketch/abbey/id)
```

How can I make use of the files?

Comment: You can try use `fit_generator`  with multiple image inputs

Comment: Thank you! I thought about using the flow_from_dataframe, but it is difficult since the .txt file is not suited for that

Answer (score 0):

'flow_from_dataframe' did the job, additionally it was necessary to preprocess the txt with pandas. This tutorial was very helpful: https://medium.com/@vijayabhaskar96/tutorial-on-keras-imagedatagenerator-with-flow-from-dataframe-8bd5776e45c1

Still having problems with matching target size of the arrays (labels seem to have the wrong format)